# CORS is not working on Cordova app with Express server

Tags: cordova, express, cors

I'm running Cordova app in the browser and I want to get some data with Fetch API from server running on another port (Express). I allowed CORS on it:

```
app.options('*', (req, res) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
});
```

But when I try to get data I get this error in the browser console (Safari);

```
Origin http://localhost:8000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

This is whole index file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const compression = require('compression');

const paths = require('./conf/paths');
const routes = require(paths.controllers.routes);

app.options('*', (req, res) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
});

app.use(helmet());
app.use(compression());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('/test', routes.users.login);

app.listen(3000);
```

My route just sends JSON data back;

```
const db = require('../conf/db');
const hash = require('../helpers/hash');
const paths = require('../conf/paths');

const User = require(paths.models.user).User;

module.exports = {

    login: (req, res, next) => {
        res.send(JSON.stringify({ result: 'test' }));
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved, thanks to the [informations](https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html) from [Enable CORS](https://enable-cors.org/index.html) website.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had success in the same situation using `app.all` but `app.use` could be used too,

```
app.all(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Comment: Just for giggles, what if you comment out `helmet` since it does do some security hocus-pocus.